# express $\mathrm{e}^{(2+i \pi/2)}$ in form $a + bi$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm just starting out into Complex numbers, polar and exponential form etc...
I can happily convert numbers such as $\mathrm{e}^{i \pi/2}$ but I'm a little stumped with how to handle the extra + 2 which appears in $\mathrm{e}^{(2+i \pi/2)}$. Can anyone explain how to handle that $2$?

Thanks,
paar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$.  Replace $a$ by $a$ and $b$ by $\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks JPi for the quick response - makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

$$e^{2+i\pi/2}=e^2e^{i\pi/2}=e^{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi 2\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi 2\right)\right)=ie^2$$